# What is error in this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors, nsmutablearray

i ma adding value in an array by using this syntax

```
[Listoflatlong addObject: sObject.startLocLat];
```

but it is giving error that is error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `addObject:`. I am adding `double` value of `sObject.startLocLat` in array `Listoflatlong`. How remove this error?

Comment: try using this [Listoflatlong addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",sObject.startLocLat]]; if u r using NSMutableArray

Comment: So many duplicate answers in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with a [numerical primitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Primitive_data_types), you should add an [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object to an `NSMutableArray`, e.g. to add a `double`, use the [`+numberWithDouble:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-numberWithDouble_) class method:

```
[Listoflatlong addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sObject.startLocLat]];
```

As a matter of Objective-C convention, you should name your mutable array instance uncapitalized, i.e. `listOfLatLong`. Classes get capitalized. Instance variables do not (should not).

Answer (score 0):

If `sObject.startLocLat` is a `double`, then to store it in an array you need to use NSNumber:

```
[Listoflatlong addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sObject.startLocLat]];
```

Then you can use `[[Listoflatlong objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]` to retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a double value directly whereas the syntax clearly asks you for an Object. Try using

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:<#(double)value#>]
```

Hope it helps.